# Reply to Message Skype4Py

Tags: python, skype, skype4py

I just don't find any tutorial or easy-to-understand snippet to do that simple task.
I have a method OnMessageStatus which is called everytime I get an incoming Message.

The signature is OnMessageStatus(Message, Status):
Where Message is an object of the following type: http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Skype4Py.chat.ChatMessage-class.html

I can't figure out how I can reply in the same chat / group chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get chat from `ChatMessage.Chat` and call its method [`SendMessage`](http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Skype4Py.chat.Chat-class.html#SendMessage).

Following simple callback will do the trick:

```
def OnMessageStatus(msg, status):
    if status == Skype4Py.cmsReceived:
        msg.Chat.SendMessage("n/a")
```